# Can We Say Near To Mean Similar?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary

A friend called me overseas and asked me about the weather, which I knew was similar to the weather in his location. I answered him by saying: "It is near to what you have.". I meant the weathers are similar.  Was my expression correct language-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use the adverb "nearly" (without 'to') or the prepositional expression "close to" in the context you outline, but there are some dialects (including in my own native Hiberno-English, but certainly elsewhere too) where 'near' would be fine. In the Irish dialects I'm referring to, the 'to' is unnecessary:

"The weather [we're having here] is near [to] what you have."

In short, your usage is fine: it's logical, elegant and comprehensible, though it's not the standard form of English as taught as a foreign language.

However, if you want to stick to standard English, you should use expressions like "similar to", "close to" or "like".

Answer (score 2):

While it would probably be understood in context, it isn't the right word to use.  "Similar" is the right word, "like" is also possible.

Comment: ***close*** isn't quite the right word either, but imho it's a lot better than ***near*** for the context. Compare the relative frequencies of [***close** to what I mean* and ***near** to what I mean*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=close+to+what+I+mean%2Cnear+to+what+I+mean&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: 'near [to] is fine in some dialects (including mine) in spoken language. It's perfectly comprehensible and perfectly elegant.